# REST and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, rest

when I use jquery and ajax am I using REST? Is rest just asynchronous  post/get etc?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: No. It has more to do it with how the service urls are formed. And the method like GET POST PUT.

Comment: @Sirko _"Actually REST refers only to GET requests"_: not quite. You can use all HTTP methods (GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE...) with REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It has more to do it with how the service urls are formed. And also the methods to access them GET, POST, PUT etc

Example,

> GET /item/all  <- Gives all items
>
> GET /item/id   <- Gives item identified by id
>
> POST /item   <- Creates new item
>
> PUT /item/id   <- Updates item identified by id
>
> DELETE /item/id   <- Deletes item identified by id

Comment: so is it correct to say that I could use .net MVC as the service sitting on the net  then use jquery to post to it?

Comment: Yes if it exposes the service in REST form. It does not have to fully REST full to call it from browser but REST full is advised.